# Electing a new leader in distributed systems

Tags: message-queue, distributed-system, consensus

I have the following problem:

I have a distributed system where I need to reach a consensus in one way or another when choosing a leader.

I have a group of `players` that communicate with each other via messages. In order for these players to progress from a stage to another someone has to keep track of their progress. Currently, there are 2 types of players:
`leader`---when he receives N-1 `done` messages (for `N-1` players) he is responsible for broadcasting to all other users state change
`follower` ---he is responsible for getting the messages of the leader and updating his internal state-machine.

Each player  receives messages from 2 pipelines:
-`Status pipeline` - He receives an array of type
`[user1,user2,user3...userN]`  where each element is the user that is online.
-`Message pipeline` -Push based notification. Follower users will post here messages that they are ready for the next step. The leader will keep track of the `DONE` counter and when the threshold is reached he will broadcast `ADVANCE to next step`.

For a better idea i included a picture:
[image]

I do not know how to deal with leader reelection. In case the leader disconnects (this can be implemented with a timeout), how can the other nodes decide who is the next leader and if they pick randomly, should the current leader be stored in the database? I mean they only exchange messages there's nothing on the server, like a global variable or something.

Answer (score 0):

What you basically need is to implement both 2 phase commit and a leader election recipe. Now, either you can implement them on your own (2 phase commit is well documented, and yes, you would need a shared storage), or if you have the flexibility to use a distributed open source co-ordination service, zookeeper would be your best bet. Have a look at the below article on apache zookeeper's page where they discuss both the recipes which you need. Hope this helps.

https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/recipes.html#sc_recipes_twoPhasedCommit